# how to write code for two background colors

Tags: css, background, background-color

Attached is what I am trying to achieve. I am trying to write code for two background colors. One will fill the entire background, the other will be 60% inside the other, with a drop shadow. Would someone please help me get this...thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zaup.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example:

On your CSS:

```
.box1 { background-color: gray; }
.box2 { background-color: yellow; margin: 0 auto; padding: 10px; width: 60%; }
.box3 { border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px; }
```

On your HTML:

```
<div class="box1">
    <div class="box2">
        <div class="box3">Content here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is with flexbox, here is a useful guide.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I also left a [JSFiddle](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) with the complete example.
I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Paul, you will get what you want by following Dadive's solution, which doesn't require any Flexbox at all. The only bit of code that you need to add in order to get the shadow effect is this:

```
.box2 { box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #000; }
```

This will give you a blur all around your yellow container, which is where I assume you want the box-shadow to be. If you are thinking about the contents inside the yellow container, then you can make `.box3` a flex container by setting it to `.box3 { display: flex; }`. I hope this helps.